# Derived table name in summary function in r

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I have generated my model using

```
assign(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '') , glm(tv1 ~., family=binomial(link='logit'), 
                                           data=train70))
```

Now I would like to run the summary function on my output. I used the below code but rather then generating the co-efficents etc for my model I get a summary of a chracter variable. How do I tweak my code to run the summary for the model?

```
summary(paste("Model", MV1, sep = ''))
```

Comment: Do not use `assign`. Put your models in a list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get` function, which helps you evaluate the object with the name of a character. Here is a toy example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x + rnorm(10)
assign("model", lm(y ~ x))
summary(get("model"))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.4863 -0.3476 -0.1218  0.2645  0.7806 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.01189    0.30979  -0.038     0.97    
x            0.93818    0.04993  18.791 6.65e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4535 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9778,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9751 
F-statistic: 353.1 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 6.646e-08
```

So for your case, `summary(get(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '')))` should work for you.

Comment: Thats great mate. Thanks for your help